# Updating some columns of one row from another of same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have some data that looks like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/21a06/1

```
id   step   valA   valB   valC
------------------------------
100  1      NULL   2      3
101  2      4      5      6
102  3      7      NULL   9
103  3      10     11     12
104  4      13     14     15
105  4      NULL   14     15
106  5      NULL   18     19
107  5      20     18     19
```

id is a unique field.  I'm trying to come up with a query that will update values on a given row from certain columns (in this example valA and valB) of the next row.  Only where 'step' of both rows match (there are never expected to be more than two rows matching), if the value of either column valA or valB is NULL on the first row (with lower listid value), the value of the same column from the next row is copied to the first row.

So in the table example given above the row for id=102 should have valB updated to 11 (to match valB of the next row with id=103).  Also, the row for id=106 should have valA updated to 20 (to match valA of the next row with id=107).  Any given pair of rows may have the conditions met for both valA and valB at the same time (both NULL).  id=100 row is unaffected because there is no other row with step=1, and id=105 row is also not touched because the NULL is on the second row of the 'step' pair.

The result would look like this:

```
id   step   valA   valB   valC
------------------------------
100  1      NULL   2      3
101  2      4      5      6
102  3      7      11     9
103  3      10     11     12
104  4      13     14     15
105  4      NULL   14     15
106  5      20     18     19
107  5      20     18     19
```

If it makes it easier, the NULL on id=105 row could also be updated to the value from id=104 row (13), but it's not necessary.

I found some questions that looked related and I tried various things with inner joins, etc. but wasn't able to come up with anything that worked.  This is beyond my basic SQL experience.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to get the first row of the matching pair. Then use `APPLY` to get the substitute value from the second pair.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
        Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY step ORDER BY id)
    FROM TestTable
)
SELECT
    c.id, 
    c.step, 
    valA = ISNULL(c.valA, x.valA), 
    valB = ISNULL(c.valB, x.valB),
    c.valC
FROM CTE c
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT TOP(1) *
    FROM TestTable t
    WHERE
        t.id > c.id
        AND t.step = c.step
    ORDER BY t.id
) x
WHERE
    Rn = 1
    OR (c.valA IS NULL OR c.valB IS NULL)

UNION ALL

SELECT
    id, step, valA, valB, valC
FROM CTE
WHERE
    Rn = 2
    AND valA IS NOT NULL
    AND valB IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Id;
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/21a06/2/0)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going through it to understand how it works better but it looks like it would do what I need.  It seems though that the changes are made to c, not the original table.  E.g. if I follow with select * from TestTable, I get the original data.  Is it possible to make this so the original table rows are modified?